# Do you use any client-side javascript library or jQuery plugin for WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ruby, websocket

I need to deal with breaking connections and other standard things which are not handled by WebSockets yet. Something tells me that there must be plenty of plugins to do this. Do you use anything like that or write your own routines?

I need it for the client side, since I use Sinatra on the server side.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but I suggest using node.js + socket.io. Really simple to get going and works across all major browsers (websockets alone does not). http://socket.io/

Comment: Using javascript (even via coffeescript) for the server side is not really attractive. There is a jQuery plugin to deal with old browsers, which do not provide WebSockets: https://github.com/ffdead/jquery-graceful-websocket and I wonder if guys use it or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common issues at hand: supporting older browsers that don't natively support WebSockets and automatic reconnect (in case of breaking connections).

Older browsers are supported by several vendors and products through emulation using different transports - what you need to look at is how good the emulation is. [Here's a brief article](https://kaazing.com/2011/11/17/the-industrys-best-websocket-emulation-real-time-web-apps-for-all-your-customers-even-if-theyre-on-ie6/) on the topic describing the problem and Kaazing's solution [disclaimer: I work for Kaazing].

The Kaazing WebSocket Gateway also provides automatic reconnect - in case the connection breaks.

You can download the [free developer version of the Kaazing Gateway](https://kaazing.com/download/) - to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! Automatic reconnect is not that hard to implement - AFAIS, its `setTimer` and check for `socket.readyState`. There are also free polyfills for WebSocket, e.g. check Web Sockets section at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills